# how to use one file in a few threads

Tags: multithreading, excel, tabpage

I have application where I'm using a tabPage controls. In each of this controls I read data from the excel file and then analyze the data in separate threads. How make to a few threads can read data from one excel file?

Answer (score 0):

read data into memory and synchronize access from different threads by `mutex` (probably `CriticalSection` in your case)

Answer (score 0):

Here are links to some samples:

[Win API, for C and C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `EnterCriticalSection`

[Also, in C#, nice threading article](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the COM interface to Excel, and you are working on a single workbook, you can only read/write from/to of Excel from a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to read the data in the memory. This data in the record format could be put up in a Queue where threads can pick up tasks. You may want to look at the java.util.concurrent package in Java.